# Dropzone already attached in Angular 2 or Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dropzone.js

I have a programmatically created Dropzone inside an Angular 2 Component wich I would like to have attached to the **body** so my entire website is the "dropzone" for uploading.

Every time the component is instantiated it will try to attach the dropzone.

`this.dropzone = new Dropzone('body', this.createOptions());`

First time I execute this it works, but as soon as I re-navigate to the component I get the **Dropzone already attached.** error.

When searching for a solution I noticed the option to use `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false`

But when trying this I get a compilation error of Typescript: **Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property.**

So my question is: how can I detach the drop zone from the body and re-attach it when necessary? Or how should I proceed to have this functionality?

I am using typings @types/dropzone from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dropzone version 4.3.34

Thanks

Comment: You can also set autoDiscover to false - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935953/using-dropzone-with-typescript/51816623#51816623

Answer (score 2):

I've used [ngx-dropzone-wrapper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper) and you can bind your dropzone like this

```
<div class="upload-area"
     #dz=dz
     [dropzone]="dzImageConfig"
     (error)="onUploadError($event)"
     (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)"
     (sending)="onSending($event)"
     (removedFile)="onRemovedFile($event)">

</div>
```

You should not have to bind to a variable using this library but you can.

Edit: Make sure callbacks are camel case. E.g. "removedFile" not "removedfile"
https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/blob/master/README.md
"Event names are in camel case (not lower case)."

Answer (score 0):

`Dropzone.instances` have dropzone attatched instances. You can check them.