# Using Dropzone with Typescript

Tags: typescript, dropzone.js

I have an app that uses dropzone 4.3 and is written in Typescript.  Prior to converting it to typescript, we had to set a global variable on Dropzone and everything was happy.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

I've pulled in these node packages:

```
    "@types/dropzone": "^4.3.35",
    "dropzone": "4.3.0",
```

Now, the autodiscover line gives me this error:

```
Error   TS2686  'Dropzone' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

In order to solve that problem, I added this:

```
import * as Dropzone from 'dropzone';
```

Now, I'm left with this error:

```
Error   TS2540  Cannot assign to 'autoDiscover' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Currently facing the same issue. Do you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, although a bit hacky using an eval statement.  eval("DropZone.autoDiscover = false");

Comment: Very nice hacky statement. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set autoDiscover to false as follows

```
import * as Dropzone from "dropzone";    
const dz = Dropzone
dz.autoDiscover = false;
```

I found this from this link https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/blob/fb39139147f3a6d72bcaff51c3c32e2a54e31c9d/src/lib/dropzone.directive.ts#L60